# Make my image blur without using renderscript for supporting all API versions

Tags: android

I want to make my image blurry. I am trying to do that but I can't achieve it. When I am using the renderscript it is working(the image has blurred) but it doesn't support the lower version API, only it supports from Android 4.2.
So, I don't want to us renderscript, (for the lower API's. 
Please give insight into the solution friends.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     Button btnLoadImage;
     ImageView imageResult;

     final int RQS_IMAGE1 = 1;

     Uri source;
     Bitmap bitmapMaster;
     Canvas canvasMaster;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      btnLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loadimage);

      imageResult = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.result);

      btnLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(
          Intent.ACTION_PICK,
          android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_IMAGE1);
       }
      });
     }

     @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
       switch (requestCode) {
       case RQS_IMAGE1:
        source = data.getData();

        try {
         bitmapMaster = BitmapFactory
           .decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(
             source));
         loadGrayBitmap(bitmapMaster);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
        }

        break;
       }
      }
     }




     private void loadGrayBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

      if (bitmap != null) {

          Bitmap outBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);

          RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(getApplicationContext());

          ScriptIntrinsicBlur blurscript = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));

          Allocation in = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, bitmap);
          Allocation out = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, outBitmap);

          blurscript.setRadius(25.f);

          blurscript.setInput(in);
          blurscript.forEach(out);

          out.copyTo(outBitmap);

          bitmap.recycle();

          imageResult.setImageBitmap(outBitmap);
//        return outBitmap;

      }

     }
}
```

Comment: @FrankN.Stein not blurred its same as original image

Comment: Even better: http://trickyandroid.com/advanced-blurring-techniques/

Comment: @FrankN.Stein ya its working but, supports only from api version 4.2 and above but i need it from lower version api too

Comment: NO. The FastBlur method (2 ms) **doesn't use RenderScript**.

Comment: If you use the support library, RenderScript intrinsics can be run as far back as FroYo (version 8).

Comment: See http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/09/renderscript-in-android-support-library.html for details.

Comment: @StephenHines how can i download the support librard how to use tat in my project can u pls tell me

Comment: It's part of the Android SDK. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html has some documentation about getting it set up in Eclipse. There may be some other tutorials on the web too.